# How to overload += operator to return a string?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I just have a quick question: how can I overload the += operator to return a string. Here is what I have tried, but with no success.

```
Student& Student::operator+=(const Student& RHS)
{
    string temp_string;
    temp_string = "( " + RHS.get_name() + ", " + RHS.get_grade() + ") ";
    return temp_string;
}
```

Comment: Change the return type to be a `std::string`?

Comment: @NathanOliver How did you come up with that idea? o_o

Comment: Keep in mind this is going to be confusing and unexpected. It looks like you're not even modifying the current object. I would very much suggest not doing this.

Comment: and don't return a reference on a temporary... You're hijacking the += operator. Not advised.

Comment: Before you write this, you should take one step back and ask yourself what it means to add a student to another student. Most likely you want to use a named function rather than such an operator overload.

Comment: LHS student absorbs the essence of RHS student! Vampire code!

Answer (score 7):

Pure technically:

```
// v NO reference here!
std::string Student::operator+=(const Student& rhs)
{
    string temp_string;
    temp_string = "( " + rhs.get_name() + ", " + rhs.get_grade() + ") ";
    return temp_string;
}
```

***BUT:***

What shall be the meaning of this? Very first, what shall be the result of the sum of two students in general? Another student? How would you interpret that in human language? Starts being confusing already. Then have a look at the following:

```
int x = 10;
x += 12;
```

You expect `x` afterwards to hold the value 22. Especially: x got modified (unless you added zero...). Your operator, in contrast, does not modify `this` in any way - it does not even look at... How would you interpret adding another student to `this` *now*? Especially: with an operator + accepting two students, you could have returned some kind of pair or family, but with +=, changing the result type??? What if `x += 7` did not modify x, but returned a double? Do you see how confusing this all gets?

On the other hand, I could imagine, though, that you actually are looking for the explicit cast operator instead:

```
operator std::string()
{
    std::string temp_string;
    temp_string = "( " + this->get_name() + ", " + this->get_grade() + ") ";
    return temp_string;
}
```

This way, you could add a student to a string, e. g. like this:

```
Student s;
std::string str;
str += s;
```

Or do you want to pass student to output streams? Then this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Student const& s)
{
    stream << "( " << s.get_name() << ", " << s.get_grade() << ") ";
    return stream;
}
```

With above, you could reduce cast operator to:

```
operator std::string()
{
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << *this;
    return s.str();
}
```

It's even possible to have a one liner:

```
operator std::string()
{
    return static_cast < std::ostringstream& >(std::ostringstream() << *this).str();
}
```

Well, admitted, if it is really nicer with this cast necessary is arguable...

Comment: Thank-you for your feedback, I really appreciate it :) I will look into what you have said (Admittedly, I am not very good at overloading, so your explanation really helped).

Comment: So I've implemented:

operator std::string()
{
    std::string temp_string;
    temp_string = "( " + this->get_name() + ", " + this->get_grade() + ") ";
    return temp_string;
}

And it works perfectly, but get_grade returns a float. Any ideas how to convert this into a string within this context?

Thanks!

Comment: @SamTalbot `std::to_string`?

Comment: Note that temp_string is unnecessary, you can just `return "( " + ...`

Comment: The assignment that I am working on currently wont be graded on C++11, but an older version, which I don't think support to_string unfortunately :/

Comment: @SamTalbot Well, use my streaming solution then, and you are fine (operator<< and using it within operator std::string). And you get for free: `Student s; std::cout << s;`. All posted so far is pre-C++11, so you should be fine...

Comment: @SamTalbot (side note: ostream and thus, too, ostringstream have an overloaded `operator<<(float)` - this is why the stream solution will work)